# how to decompile multiple JAR files

Tags: java, jar, decompiling

I need to decompile about 1000 jar files. Single jar files can open with JD-GUI, but I read help  (JD-GUI) and don't understand how can write script for decompiling multiple JAR files.

Comment: Can you give this decompiler a path to the JAR you need?

Answer (score 0):

Find a decompiler which can make your job using from cmd command, then gather all your JAR files in some folder. 
The next step is to build a minimum java program which takes them all and using this cmd above by executing it to some other folder.

There is a Java code for executing exe files same as manual command line.

Comment: yes, I think about, but what is a best cmd decompiler ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script to unpack all the jar into one directory structure and re-pack it as a single JAR.

Or you can write a script to decompile all the JAR assuming the decompiler has a command line interface.

BTW JD-GUI wraps a command line interface decompiler. It doesn't do the decompiling itself.